# Перехват bad request на клиенте

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

У меня есть в приложении mvc фильтр для генерации ошибок на клиент.

```
public class ClientErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Write(filterContext.Exception.Message);
        response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

В итоге если я напишу `throw new exception` у меня полетит bad request на клиент. И если я использую ajax запрос, то всё просто, этот запрос попадёт в error и там я могу с ним сделать что захочу, текст экзепшена будет в responseText. Но как мне отловить это сообщение если я использую обычный post запрос без ajax?

Comment: что значит `обычный post запрос` ? Как вы его отправляепте?

Comment: @tym32167 `@using (Html.BeginForm())
{` поля которые нужно отправить обёрнуты вот в такую вот форму. И она посылается на сервер.

Comment: Обычная форма посылается браузером и ответ отбрабатывается браузером, вы эт о не проконтролируете. Хотите контролировать - посылайте POST запрос вашим кодом и обратабывайте резульат такде вашим кодом, то бишь аяксом

Comment: @tym32167 понял, спасибо за ответ.